# Open multiple jupyter notebook with different extension config

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I share a linux server user with my teammate, and we used the same jupyter notebook server together.

However recently I found some interesting plugins, so I created a new jupyter notebook directory `~/.my_jupyter`, which is a copy of origin `~/.jupyter`, and open jupyter notebook with `config=/path/to/.my_jupyter/my_config.json` then install some plugin by [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).

But when I enable a plugin in my jupyter, the other jupyter enable that plugin too. I found that new jupyter still reference the plugin status by origin `.jupyter/nbconfig`.

I am looking for a way to change `nbconfig` path just in my jupyter, hope someone can help me figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure it out.

Create new tmux session and do following line in terminal:
`export JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=/path/to/.my_jupyter`

which `.my_jupyter` is configure path of your jupyter like origin `~/.jupyer`.